# Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) Query Parameter doesn't use Converter

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I want to be able to store a Set of fully qualified Class names as a property of a Node.  Given this Node:

```
@NodeEntity
public TestNode {
  Set<Class<?>> classSet;

  //getters and setters here
}
```

And the following custom converters:

```
public class ClassToStringConverter implements Converter<Class<?>, String> {
  @Override 
  public String convert(final Class<?> source) {
    return source.getName();
  }
}

public class StringToClassConverter implements Converter<String, Class<?>> {
  @Override 
  public String convert(final String source) {
    Class<?> returnVal = null;
    try {
      returnVal = Class.forName(source);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { }
    return returnVal;
  } 
}
```

I register the converters with Spring context as such:

```
<bean id="conversionService" 
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
  <property name="converters">
    <set>
      <bean class="my.package.ClassToStringConverter"/>
      <bean class="my.package.StringToClassConverter "/>
    </set>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Then using my repository, I can properly save and retrieve the Node, and it stores the fully qualified class name as expected using my custom converters.  However, I would like to be able to query by a Class name as such in my repository:

```
@Query("MATCH (m:TestNode) where {0} in m.classSet return m;")
public findByClassInClassSet(Class<?> clazz);
```

However, this seems to convert the Class using Class.toString() instead of using my Converter.  So it is searching for the String "class my.package.TestNode" instead of what the Converter correctly stored as "my.package.TestNode".

Am I missing something here or doing something wrong?  How can I benefit from these converters if I can't query using the Class type?

NOTE: Please excuse any typos - this code is on a disconnected network so I couldn't copy paste.  If there are any typos, I assure you that is not the problem on my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in the next milestone release for derived finders.

For your annotated query-method, SDN cannot know what you are referring to with your parameter, so it will not be able to convert it, ever.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hunger.  Please see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-534 for the request I put in for this.